# Deserializing JSON with Child and Inner Childs

Tags: c#, json.net

I am familiar with JSON.net a bit and can Deserialize the JSON with basic structure (upto one child). I am currently in process of Deserializing the JSON that is returned from Netatmo API. The structure of JSON is complicated for me. Following is the basic structure of the JSON,

```
_id
place
   location
        Dynamic Value 1
        Dynamic Value2
   altitude
   timezone
mark
measures
    Dynamic Value 1
    res
        Dynamic Value 1
              Dynamic Value 1
          Dynamic Value 2
    type
        Dynamic Value 1
        Dynamic Value 2
modules
    Dynamic Value 1
```

Dynamic Value 1 and Dynamic Value 2 represents the values that is changed for each id. The complete JSON is given below,

```
{
    "body": [{
        "_id": "70:ee:50:02:b4:8c",
        "place": {
            "location": [-35.174779762001, -5.8918476117544],
            "altitude": 52,
            "timezone": "America\/Fortaleza"
        },
        "mark": 0,
        "measures": {
            "02:00:00:02:ba:2c": {
                "res": {
                    "1464014579": [16.7, 77]
                },
                "type": ["temperature", "humidity"]
            },
            "70:ee:50:02:b4:8c": {
                "res": {
                    "1464014622": [1018.1]
                },
                "type": ["pressure"]
            }
        },
        "modules": ["02:00:00:02:ba:2c"]
    }, {
        "_id": "70:ee:50:12:40:cc",
        "place": {
            "location": [-16.074257294385, 11.135715243973],
            "altitude": 14,
            "timezone": "Africa\/Bissau"
        },
        "mark": 14,
        "measures": {
            "02:00:00:06:7b:c8": {
                "res": {
                    "1464015073": [26.6, 78]
                },
                "type": ["temperature", "humidity"]
            },
             "70:ee:50:12:40:cc": {
                "res": {
                    "1464015117": [997]
                },
                "type": ["pressure"]
            }
        },
        "modules": ["02:00:00:06:7b:c8"]
    }],
    "status": "ok",
    "time_exec": 0.010364055633545,
    "time_server": 1464015560
}
```

I am confused by looking at the complex structure of this JSON. For single level of JSON I have used this code in the past,

```
IList<lstJsonAttributes> lstSearchResults = new List<lstJsonAttributes>();
foreach (JToken objResult in objResults) {
    lstJsonAttributes objSearchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<lstJsonAttributes>(objResult.ToString());
    lstSearchResults.Add(objSearchResult);
}
```

But for so many child I have yet to understand how the object class will be created. Any guidance will highly appreciated.

Update:
This is what I have achieved so far.

I have created a main class as below,

```
public class PublicDataClass
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public PublicData_Place place { get; set; }
    public string mark { get; set; }
    public List<string> modules { get; set; }
}
```

and "Place" class is as follow,

```
public class PublicData_Place
{
    public List<string> location { get; set; }
    public string altitude { get; set; }
    public string timezone { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have Deserialized the object in the following code line,

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PublicDataClass>>(jsonString);
```

I can now successfully get all the data except the "measures" which is little bit more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net), JSON objects that have arbitrary property names but fixed schemas for their values can be deserialized as a `Dictionary<string, T>` for an appropriate type `T`.  See [Deserialize a Dictionary](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm) for details.  Thus your `"measures"` and `"res"` objects can be modeled as dictionaries.

You also need a root object to encapsulate your `List<PublicDataClass>`, since your root JSON container is an object like so: `{ "body": [{ ... }] }`.

Thus you can define your classes as follows:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<PublicDataClass> body { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public double time_exec { get; set; }
    public int time_server { get; set; }
}

public class PublicDataClass
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public PublicData_Place place { get; set; }
    public int mark { get; set; }
    public List<string> modules { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Measure> measures { get; set; }
}

public class PublicData_Place
{
    public List<double> location { get; set; } // Changed from string to double
    public double altitude { get; set; } // Changed from string to double
    public string timezone { get; set; }
}   

public class Measure
{
    public Measure()
    {
        this.Results = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
        this.Types = new List<string>();
    }

    [JsonProperty("res")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<double>> Results { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public List<string> Types { get; set; }
}
```

Then do

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
var obj = root.body;
```

Comment: Bundle of Thanks for your answer and how you have explained it. I was reaching at this point myself slowly. I used http://json2csharp.com/ to convert the JSON to C# objects. It did not successfully created object for measures but then referred to another post on SO and converted the whole JSON to dynamic object. It created everything and populated all the data. I was just looking at the objects in QuickWatch window and found out that nested child objects for Measures is created as Dictionary. Custom type is much easier to work with then nested dynamic objects.

Comment: I just tested it and it worked without any problem. Again thanks.

Comment: Brilliant explanation, really sensible way of compartmentalizing de-serialized json data.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with XML for a few years and my change to JSON structure I've got a little confused too, always that I want to see how an object look like I use this web site [jsoneditoronline](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) Just copy and paste your JSON and click on arrow to parse to an object, I hope it helps until you get used to JSON structure.